# Dynamic nested formsets Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms, django-templates

i have a django project with a circuit model and an exercise model (circuit has an exercise field which is Many2Many relationship to exercise model.
I want each user to be able to dynamically add circuits and to each circuit dynamically add exercises, so each circuit will have the exercises added to it specifically.

I managed to dynamically add the 2 formsets (circuitFormSet and exerciseFormSet) with javascript but couldn't connect between the circuits and exercises.

models.py:

```
class Exercise(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    num_of_rounds = models.IntegerField()
    
class Circuit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField() 
    exercises = models.ManyToManyField(Exercise)
```

forms.py

```
class ExerciseForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Exercise
        fields = '__all__'

class CircuitForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Circuit
        fields = '__all__'

ExerciseFormSet = formset_factory(ExerciseForm, extra=1)
CircuitFormSet = formset_factory(CircuitForm, extra=1)
```